# Proper term for "Visual Nutrition" in English?

Tags: terminology

In Arabic, we have the phrase "التغذية البصرية" which literally means "Visual Nutrition".

In Arabic, it means basically to develop an artistic eye by looking into other people's graphic designs (or art in general), hence kind of reach a saturated status of art visualizing to be able to produce better art or just simply learn from the others (e.g. browsing through Behance and Dribbble in the case of graphic design).

What is the correct respective terminology in English?

Comment: Hi Danielillo. I am a graphic designer, so this terminology will help me improve my graphic design! If there is a terminology that is specific for GD I will consider it an answer!

Comment: a term often used in English similar to you quote is "feast for the eyes" or "food for thought"

Comment: It is a lovely simile. I do get a certain satisfaction; something like when walking in a museum and enjoying the exhibits. But I can't come up with a word for it! Perhaps we should adopt the Arabic phrase, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most part, I think you answered your own question by describing it in English --- **artistic eye**

Other possible terms:

- Design Sense
- Aesthetic Vocabulary/Sense of Aesthetics
- Design/Aesthetic Inspiration
- Artistic Interpretation
- Artistic/Design/Aesthetic reference

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how the phrase is used in Arabic. If it's used as a statement of ability, the closest phrase in English is "to have an eye for ______." In the case you ask about it would be to have (or develop) an eye for design (or art).

If it's talking about the designs themselves, as Junme mentions in the comments, the designs that the person is looking at while training their eye for design (another way of saying developing their design skills) can be called "food for thought", "a feast for the eyes", or something as simple as "good examples of design" or as you mention in a comment below, "inspiration."

---

Another related phrase that's less commonly used is "feeding my appetite for ______" if you're talking about fulfilling a perceived desire or need. So you might say that looking at Dribble or Behance "feeds my appetite for good design" or something like that.

Comment: Thanks Zach. The main aim of my question is to follow accounts or blogs online that provide that kind of feed, some of them is call it "inspirations" but I am not sure if this is the most common equivalent of what I am looking for

Comment: I see. So it's more so the second paragraph of this answer then.

Answer (score 1):

In architecture we call this ***"precedent research"***, and though it's often undertaken as specific to a given project or design problem, it can also become a general process one adopts as a partially abstracted design / intellectual passion, in which one continually seeks and is enriched by examples of excellent, profound, radical or otherwise exemplary design, and which having internalized, then informs you at an *unconscious level* as you amass and synthesize more broad design literacy: this is why studying the architecture of Brunelleschi, Palladio, and Mies van der Rohe is still useful, and is not contrary to also studying more recent works from Tadao Ando, Renzo Piano, Louis Kahn and Zaha Hadid - it all helps to inform your underlying set of personal schemas and ideas about design, and to broaden your vocabulary of responses to specific design constraints and conditions.

That said, I love this phrase of yours: visual nutrition and with permission, I'd like to adopt its use!

Answer (score 0):

as a single word **peruse**

from dictionary:

peruse   verb

pe·​ruse   |   \ pə-ˈrüz     \

perused ;   perusing

1 a :   to   examine  or consider with attention and in detail   :   STUDY

b :   to look over or through in a casual or   cursory  manner

2 :   READ especially   :   to read over in an attentive or leisurely manner

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peruse  is probaly the closest